# Get Instance not returning value in nodejs

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, express

I am creating an app that uses MSSQL nodejs and express for my backend. Connection and ordinary `SELECT` query works. However, if I use this following statement, It runs fine in SSMS but using `request.query(/**some code here**/)` It does not return anything. The query is a success but blank array. Can someone check it out if there is something wrong?

My Nodejs code goes like this:

```
var queryString = "DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE (Value nvarchar(100), InstanceNames nvarchar(100), Data nvarchar(100)); Insert into @GetInstances Execute xp_regread @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server', @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'; Select InstanceNames from @GetInstances;"

request.query(queryString, function(err,data){
    if(!err) res.send(data);
}
```

My query in SSMS that gives result:

```
DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE 
   (Value nvarchar(100), InstanceNames nvarchar(100), Data nvarchar(100));

 Insert into @GetInstances 
 Execute xp_regread 
      @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
      @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server', 
      @value_name = 'InstalledInstances';

  Select InstanceNames from @GetInstances;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing an `'` on your second to last line of your SQL code `@value_name = 'InstalledInstances;` It should be: `@value_name = 'InstalledInstances';`

```
var queryString = "DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE (Value nvarchar(100), InstanceNames nvarchar(100), Data nvarchar(100)); Insert into @GetInstances Execute xp_regread @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server', @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'; Select InstanceNames from @GetInstances;"

request.query(queryString, function(err,data){
    if(!err) res.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, My bad. it's just a typo, but it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh, ok. Are your privileges correct? Did you try to run the query in SSMS with the same user that node uses?

Comment: Apparently, i should be in sysadmin role to be able to run this. Thank you for reminding me.